# Ordered and unordered choices

Tags: combinatorics

How do I use one of the following formulas:

$$n^r$$

$${n+r-1 \choose r}$$

$$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$

$${n \choose r}$$

(Where $n$ is the set size and $r$ is the number of elements being chosen)

to solve: $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3=101$$

The answer is apparently ${100 \choose 98}={100 \choose 2}=4950$ but I don't understand how they got this answer and what they substituted into which formula.

Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Do you want to find the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 101$? With which additional properties? Please make you question more precise. Then tell us how you would solve this problem if the equation were  $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 7$.

Comment: I want to find how many solutions there are with positive integers. I could use trial and error for your question as it uses a small number or I could figure out how to use the formulas.

Comment: It's best if you find a systematic way to solve the problem with a small number, not trial and error. This will teach you which formula to use and how. Write down all the possible choices for $x_1$. Then write down what the choices for $x_2$ are, for each possible $x_1$. Then count.

Comment: Would I let $r=3$ and $n=7$ then substitute into $n+r−1 \choose r$
to get ${9 \choose 3}=84$?

Comment: 84 is false. Try to understand the problem first.

Comment: This looks like a good place for a rant about one of my pet peeves: Mathematics has lots of formulas, like the 4 in the question, but these formulas are, in any reasonable exposition, attached to some words that explain what the symbols mean and what the formula is supposed to represent. If you don't understand those words, the formulas are useless. I would recommend going back to wherever you found those formulas and studying the prose around them.

Answer (score 2):

(I assume $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are positive integers.) We want to divide 101 stars between 3 people such that every person has at least one star. Imagine the 101 stars in a row:
$$\star\ \star\ \star\ \dotsb\ \star$$
Now, we want to put 2 bars in this line of stars such that each bar is between two stars. How many places are there for the bars? We can see that there are 100 spaces between adjacent stars, where we can put the bars. So, we can choose the places for the bars in $\binom{100}{2}$ ways (I hope you understand how we get the binomial). Then the first person gets all stars to the left of the first bar, the second person gets all the stars between the two bars, and the last person gets the stars beyond the second bar.

Above, I used 101 stars and 3 people. Can you extend this argument for $n$ stars and $k$ people? What do you get? What if the numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3$ can be 0 as well? Can you change the variables somewhat to accommodate this?

Comment: I understand what you've done, is this another formula I should know? $n-1 \choose r-1$

Comment: As long as you understand the reasoning, there is no need to 'know' the formula specifically. You can always 'reinvent' the formula when you need it. (Besides, $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$ is often a more useful formula to remember.)